# If $f,g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are analytic and $f=g$ on an interval of positive length, can we conclude that $f=g$ everywhere?

Tags: analytic-functions

> If $f,g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are analytic and $f=g$ on an interval of positive length, can we conclude that $f=g$ everywhere?

I guess it is more like a theorem than a problem.

I am thankful to get some for about it.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are equal on any arbitrary singleton set, then they're equal, let alone entire intervals.

Comment: You don't want to say "on any arbitrary interval". That makes the problem a bit nonsensical..

Comment: I agree with @zhw. Perhaps you mean on **an** arbitrary interval?

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. You'll want to look up the "identity principle".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Suppose that $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is analytic and on some open interval $J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, it happens that $h|_{J} \equiv 0$. Can you conclude that $h \equiv 0$?

Imagine if $h \not\equiv 0$, then there is some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x) \neq 0$. If it happens that such an $x$ exists and $x > y$ for all $y \in J$, then let $x_0 = \inf\{(x > y)\forall y\in J \mid h(x) \neq 0\}$. Using the analytic behavior of $h$, conclude that there is some $\epsilon >0$ such that $h(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$, a contradiction.